# Is it possible to run a program when an installer starts up?

Tags: wix

I'm currently using wix to write an installer. What I need it to do is to run a configuration tool once the installer starts. This tool relies on some DLLs. Is it possible to this? The configuration tool and DLLs will be in the binary table.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) tag.  You will want to use the `ExeCommand` attribute to specify the exe you want to execute.

Comment: Sadly that wasn't exactly what I was after. Instead of putting the program in the Binary table I had to write the program to disk and then run it before install finalize. It ended up working but not the way I wanted it to.